# UITextField auto-delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

When a user holds down the delete key for a certain amount of time, the `UITextField` begins deleting multiple characters at once. I'm trying to create a `UITextField` that has a # as the first character. This # should never be deleted. The code below works to prevent the user from deleting the # accept when the user types in many characters, and then proceeds to hold down the delete key until `UITextField` deletes multiple characters at once. The user is then able to delete all characters from the `UITextField` despite the logic below. How can this be?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if (newLength < 1)
        return NO;
    else if (newString.length == 0)
        return NO;

    return (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified this method is being called when the user holds down the delete key?

Comment: BTW - what's the point of `newString`? Your `newLength` will always equal `newString.length` so just use `newLength`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would be better:

```
- (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (![textView.text hasPrefix:@"#"]) {
        textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@", textView.text];
    }
}
```

This way, at any point, if your text view doesn't have a '#' as a prefix, this puts one in.  Otherwise, if the user types 10 characters, then goes back and erases the '#' the system won't recognize it, or if they highlight all of the text and erase it.  If later code depends on the '#' char, I'd say this is probably more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method is technically allowed to modify the text field directly, but give this a try and let me know how it goes.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if ( newString.length > 30 )
        return( NO );

    if ( newString.length < 1 )
        newString = @"#";

    textField.text = newString;  // I'll change the string myself thanks
    return( NO );                // string's already changed, don't change it again
}
```